# How to get a top level configuration (type is System.Configuration.Configuration) from ConfigurationManager?

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

I tried:

```
((ConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("appSettings"))).CurrentConfiguration
```

but got `System.InvalidCastException`.

I do **not** want to use `ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration` as it requires the path of the configuration file, which varies in our case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) Appsettings section is type of NameValueCollection and not ConfigurationSection, hence its InavalidCastException. To avoid exception above code should be

```
((NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("appSettings"))
```

2) Apart from `AppSettings` and `ConnectionStrings` any other section of configuration file can be read as below

```
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("startup") as ConfigurationSection;
```

3) If path of configuration file varies then its helpful to use Assembly code base to get path, as shown below

```
var path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
var path1 = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase;
```

Comment: Thanks Saty. But No.2 doesn't work.
`var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("startup") as ConfigurationSection; //section is {System.Configuration.IgnoreSection}`  
`var topLevel = section.CurrentConfiguration; //topLevel is still null`  

**My configuration file**  
<configuration>  
    <startup>  
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />  
    </startup>  
</configuration>

Comment: Using OpenMappedExeConfiguration gets a System.Configuration.Configuration.
`var path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + ".config";`
`var topLevel = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path); //topLevel not null`